# Segmentation Fault error in 3D array memory allocation

Tags: c

I have a pointer variable `int ***a` in C. I'm passing it to a function as `&a` i.e reference. In the function I'm getting a pointer variable of type `int ****a`.
I'm allocating memory like this.

```
*a=(int***)malloc(no1*sizeof(int**));
some loop from 0 to no1
    (*a)[++l]=(int**)malloc((no1+1)*sizeof(int*));
some loop from 0 to no1
    (*a)[l][h]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```

This is only the time I allocated memory. The actual program is not given; no error here.
But when I'm going to do this:

```
(*a)[l][h][0]=no1;
```

It's giving me a "Segmentation Fault" error and I can't understand why.

***UPDATE:***
I have wrote a sample program which is to allocate the memory only. This is also giving "segmentation fault" error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void allocate(int ****a)
{
    int i,j,k;
    if(((*a)=(int***)malloc(5*sizeof(int**)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError in allocation of double pointer array\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)if(((*a)[i]=(int**)malloc(4*sizeof(int*)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError in allocation of single pointer array on index [%d]\n",i);
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;i++)
            if(((*a)[i][j]=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int)))==NULL)
            {
                printf("\nError in allocation of array on index [%d][%d]\n",i,j);
                exit(0);
            }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;i++)
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                (*a)[i][j][k]=k;
}

main()
{
    int ***a;
    int i,j,k;
    allocate(&a);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;i++)
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                printf("\na[%d][%d][%d]  = %d ",i,j,k,a[i][j][k]);
}
```

Comment: That's not a 3D array. That's a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer. And [being a three-star programmer is **not** a compliment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: It would probably help if you could expand the pseudocode for the allocation loops. Also you could state what l and h are in the piece of code that segfaults.

Comment: Yeah. Its not 3D array. Sorry for that. actually the situation is like that. Maybe I have to switch to 4star variable. Please help if you cant point out any problem in the given chunk of code.

l & h are started from 0 0. But at the index 0 0 0 its getting error. no need to go any other index :(

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal Instead of adding *another* level of indirection, what if you used an *actual* 3D array? (Or at least a pointer to its first element...) Like this: `int (*arr)[y][z] = malloc(x * sizeof(arr[0]));`

Comment: @H2CO3 Assuming VLAs are tested for and claim support on your implementation (most all do), I concur, that is a *much* cleaner approach. (i'd check `sizeof()` with VLAs, however, I'm pretty sure it doesn't work and you still have to do the math by-hand).

Comment: @WhozCraig I learnt it on Stack Overflow. :) (oh, and not to mention how little I care about Windows support :P)

Comment: @WhozCraig `sizeof` works perfectly fine with VLAs.

Comment: Actually the suppose a[x][y][z] is the varriable. then a[x] is an double pointer array. and each double pointer is holding a 2D array but all 2D arrays are not of same row col in my case. they are variable. So I think the way I'm doing its the way considering time and space complexity. but why that error is occuring?

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal: Please post actual C code. You probably have an error in the allocation code. We can't help you otherwise (apart from stylistic advice ;) )

Comment: If you show us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), we might be able to help you. Otherwise it is very difficult for us.

Comment: @H2CO3 no kidding. gotta go try that. I thought the last time I did my compiler bitched at me. Now I'm curious. thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're welcome. [Here's some demo](http://ideone.com/7w2vu0) using GCC on Linux (presumably Linux, anyway.)

Comment: @H2CO3 well look at that. Works on my clang on my Mac too (of course =P). Thanks again, sir.

Comment: Your code has: `for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;i++)
            if(((*a)[i][j]=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int)))==NULL)`; the second loop should be incrementing `j`, not `i`.  Be very careful with copy'n'paste.

Answer (score 5):

#### Revised code from question

Your code has:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;i++)
```

several times.  The second loop should be incrementing j, not i. Be very careful with copy'n'paste.

This code does not crash (but does leak).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocate(int ****a);

void allocate(int ****a)
{
    int i,j,k;
    printf("allocate: 1B\n");
    if(((*a)=(int***)malloc(5*sizeof(int**)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError in allocation of double pointer array\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("allocate: 1A\n");

    printf("allocate: 2B\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(((*a)[i]=(int**)malloc(4*sizeof(int*)))==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError in allocation of single pointer array on index [%d]\n",i);
            exit(0);
        }
    printf("allocate: 2A\n");
    printf("allocate: 3B\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            if(((*a)[i][j]=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int)))==NULL)
            {
                printf("\nError in allocation of array on index [%d][%d]\n",i,j);
                exit(0);
            }
    printf("allocate: 3A\n");

    printf("allocate: 4B\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                (*a)[i][j][k]=k;
    printf("allocate: 4A\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int ***a;
    int i,j,k;
    allocate(&a);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                printf("a[%d][%d][%d]  = %d\n",i,j,k,a[i][j][k]);
}
```

#### Previous answers

Since you've not shown us most of the code, it is hard to predict how you're mishandling it, but equally, since you are getting a core dump, you must be mishandling something.

Here is some working code — not checked with `valgrind` since that is not available for Mac OS X 10.8 — that seems to work.  The error recovery for allocation failure is not complete, and the function to destroy the fully allocated array is also missing.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int ***allocate_3d_array(int no1, int ****a)
{
    *a = (int***)malloc(no1 * sizeof(int**));
    if (*a == 0)
        return 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        if (((*a)[l]=(int**)malloc((no1+1)*sizeof(int*))) == 0)
        {
            while (l > 0)
                free((*a)[--l]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
        {
            if (((*a)[l][h]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int))) == 0)
            {
                /* Leak! */
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                (*a)[l][h][k] = 10000 * l + 100 * h + k;

    return *a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int no1 = 5;
    int ***a = 0;
    int ***b = allocate_3d_array(no1, &a);
    const char *pad[] = { "  ", "\n" };
    assert(b == a);

    if (a != 0)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                    printf("a[%d][%d][%d] = %.6d%s", l, h, k, a[l][h][k], pad[k]);

        // free memory - added by harpun; reformatted by Jonathan Leffler
        // Would be a function normally — see version 2 code.
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
                free(a[l][h]);
            free(a[l]);
        }
        free(a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
a[0][0][0] = 000000  a[0][0][1] = 000001
a[0][1][0] = 000100  a[0][1][1] = 000101
a[0][2][0] = 000200  a[0][2][1] = 000201
a[0][3][0] = 000300  a[0][3][1] = 000301
a[0][4][0] = 000400  a[0][4][1] = 000401
a[1][0][0] = 010000  a[1][0][1] = 010001
a[1][1][0] = 010100  a[1][1][1] = 010101
a[1][2][0] = 010200  a[1][2][1] = 010201
a[1][3][0] = 010300  a[1][3][1] = 010301
a[1][4][0] = 010400  a[1][4][1] = 010401
a[2][0][0] = 020000  a[2][0][1] = 020001
a[2][1][0] = 020100  a[2][1][1] = 020101
a[2][2][0] = 020200  a[2][2][1] = 020201
a[2][3][0] = 020300  a[2][3][1] = 020301
a[2][4][0] = 020400  a[2][4][1] = 020401
a[3][0][0] = 030000  a[3][0][1] = 030001
a[3][1][0] = 030100  a[3][1][1] = 030101
a[3][2][0] = 030200  a[3][2][1] = 030201
a[3][3][0] = 030300  a[3][3][1] = 030301
a[3][4][0] = 030400  a[3][4][1] = 030401
a[4][0][0] = 040000  a[4][0][1] = 040001
a[4][1][0] = 040100  a[4][1][1] = 040101
a[4][2][0] = 040200  a[4][2][1] = 040201
a[4][3][0] = 040300  a[4][3][1] = 040301
a[4][4][0] = 040400  a[4][4][1] = 040401
```

Compare this with what you've got.  You could add many more diagnostic print messages.  If this doesn't help sufficiently, create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) analogous to this that demonstrates the problem in your code without any extraneous material.

#### Version 2 of the code

This is a somewhat more complex version of the code that simulates memory allocation failures after N allocations (and a test harness that runs it with every value of N from 0 up to 35, where there are actually only 30 allocations for the array.  It also includes code to release the array (similar to, but different from, the code that was edited into my answer by [harpun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283084/harpun).  The interaction at the end with the line containing the PID means that I can check memory usage with `ps` in another terminal window.  (Otherwise, I don't like programs that do that sort of thing — I suppose I should run the `ps` from my program via `system()`, but I'm feeling lazy.)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int fail_after = 0;
static int num_allocs = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (fail_after > 0 && num_allocs++ >= fail_after)
    {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    return malloc(size);
}

static int ***allocate_3d_array(int no1, int ****a)
{
    *a = (int***)xmalloc(no1 * sizeof(int**));
    if (*a == 0)
        return 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        if (((*a)[l]=(int**)xmalloc((no1+1)*sizeof(int*))) == 0)
        {
            for (int l1 = 0; l1 < l; l1++)
                free((*a)[l1]);
            free(*a);
            *a = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
        {
            if (((*a)[l][h]=(int*)xmalloc(2*sizeof(int))) == 0)
            {
                /* Release prior items in current row */
                for (int h1 = 0; h1 < h; h1++)
                    free((*a)[l][h1]);
                free((*a)[l]);
                /* Release items in prior rows */
                for (int l1 = 0; l1 < l; l1++)
                {
                    for (int h1 = 0; h1 < no1; h1++)
                        free((*a)[l1][h1]);
                    free((*a)[l1]);
                }
                free(*a);
                *a = 0;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                (*a)[l][h][k] = 10000 * l + 100 * h + k;

    return *a;
}

static void destroy_3d_array(int no1, int ***a)
{
    if (a != 0)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
                free(a[l][h]);
            free(a[l]);
        }
        free(a);
    }
}

static void test_allocation(int no1)
{
    int ***a = 0;
    int ***b = allocate_3d_array(no1, &a);
    const char *pad[] = { "  ", "\n" };
    assert(b == a);

    if (a != 0)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    if (a[l][h][k] != l * 10000 + h * 100 + k)
                        printf("a[%d][%d][%d] = %.6d%s", l, h, k, a[l][h][k], pad[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    destroy_3d_array(no1, a);
}

int main(void)
{
    int no1 = 5;

    for (fail_after = 0; fail_after < 33; fail_after++)
    {
        printf("Fail after: %d\n", fail_after);
        num_allocs = 0;
        test_allocation(no1);
    }

    printf("PID %d - waiting for some data to exit:", (int)getpid());
    fflush(0);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Note how painful the memory recovery is.  As before, not tested with `valgrind`, but I take reassurance from [harpun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283084/harpun)'s test on the previous version.

#### Version 3 — Clean bill of health from [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)

This code is very similar to the test in version 2.  It fixes a memory leak in the clean-up when a memory allocation fails in the leaf level allocations.  The program no longer prompts for inputs (much preferable); it takes an optional single argument that is the number of allocations to fail after.  Testing with `valgrind` showed that with an argument 0-6, there were no leaks, but with argument 7 there was a leak.  It didn't take long to spot the problem and fix it.  (It's easier when the machine running `valgrind` is available — it was powered down over the long weekend for general site electrical supply upgrade.)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int fail_after = 0;
static int num_allocs = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (fail_after > 0 && num_allocs++ >= fail_after)
    {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    return malloc(size);
}

static int ***allocate_3d_array(int no1, int ****a)
{
    *a = (int***)xmalloc(no1 * sizeof(int**));
    if (*a == 0)
        return 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        if (((*a)[l]=(int**)xmalloc((no1+1)*sizeof(int*))) == 0)
        {
            for (int l1 = 0; l1 < l; l1++)
                free((*a)[l1]);
            free(*a);
            *a = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
        {
            if (((*a)[l][h]=(int*)xmalloc(2*sizeof(int))) == 0)
            {
                /* Release prior items in current (partial) row */
                for (int h1 = 0; h1 < h; h1++)
                    free((*a)[l][h1]);
                /* Release items in prior (complete) rows */
                for (int l1 = 0; l1 < l; l1++)
                {
                    for (int h1 = 0; h1 < no1; h1++)
                        free((*a)[l1][h1]);
                }
                /* Release entries in first (complete) level of array */
                for (int l1 = 0; l1 < no1; l1++)
                    free((*a)[l1]);
                free(*a);
                *a = 0;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                (*a)[l][h][k] = 10000 * l + 100 * h + k;

    return *a;
}

static void destroy_3d_array(int no1, int ***a)
{
    if (a != 0)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
                free(a[l][h]);
            free(a[l]);
        }
        free(a);
    }
}

static void test_allocation(int no1)
{
    int ***a = 0;
    int ***b = allocate_3d_array(no1, &a);
    const char *pad[] = { "  ", "\n" };
    assert(b == a);

    if (a != 0)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    if (a[l][h][k] != l * 10000 + h * 100 + k)
                        printf("a[%d][%d][%d] = %.6d%s", l, h, k, a[l][h][k], pad[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    destroy_3d_array(no1, a);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int no1 = 5;
    int fail_limit = 33;

    if (argc == 2)
        fail_limit = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (fail_after = 0; fail_after < fail_limit; fail_after++)
    {
        printf("Fail after: %d\n", fail_after);
        num_allocs = 0;
        test_allocation(no1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Version 4 — Fewer memory allocations

<sup>*Update 2014-12-20*</sup>

The code above makes a lot of memory allocations, which complicates the release and error recovery.  Here is an alternative version that makes just 3 allocations, one for the vector of pointers to pointers, one for the array of pointers, and one for the array of integers.  It then sets the pointers to point to the correct places in memory.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int fail_after = 0;
static int num_allocs = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (fail_after > 0 && num_allocs++ >= fail_after)
    {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    return malloc(size);
}

static int ***allocate_3d_array(int no1, int ****a)
{
    int ***d0 = (int***)xmalloc(no1 * sizeof(int**));
    int **d1 = (int **)xmalloc(no1 * no1 * sizeof(int *));
    int *d2 = (int *)xmalloc(no1 * no1  * 2 * sizeof(int));

    if (d0 == 0 || d1 == 0 || d2 == 0)
    {
        free(d0);
        free(d1);
        free(d2);
        *a = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
    {
        d0[l] = &d1[l * no1];
        for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
        {
            d0[l][h] = &d2[(l * no1 + h) * 2];
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                d0[l][h][k] = l * 10000 + h * 100 + k;
        }
    }

    *a = d0;
    return *a;
}

static void destroy_3d_array(int ***a)
{
    if (a != 0)
    {
        free(a[0][0]);
        free(a[0]);
        free(a);
    }
}

static void test_allocation(int no1)
{
    int ***a = 0;
    int ***b = allocate_3d_array(no1, &a);
    const char *pad[] = { "  ", "\n" };
    assert(b == a);

    if (a != 0)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < no1; l++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < no1; h++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    if (a[l][h][k] != l * 10000 + h * 100 + k)
                        printf("Oops: a[%d][%d][%d] = %.6d%s", l, h, k, a[l][h][k], pad[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    destroy_3d_array(a);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int no1 = 5;
    int fail_limit = 4;

    if (argc == 2)
        fail_limit = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (fail_after = 0; fail_after < fail_limit; fail_after++)
    {
        printf("Fail after: %d\n", fail_after);
        num_allocs = 0;
        test_allocation(no1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This has a clean bill of health with GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.1, checked with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) version valgrind-3.11.0.SVN (built from an SVN tree with some necessary fixes for Mac OS X, but not enough suppressions).

The diagnostic print (starting with 'Oops') was triggered while I developed the answer; I had my pointer calculations wrong at the time.

Comment: +1 .. but shouldn't the cast of `malloc`'s return value be avoided?

Comment: The allocation is valid. I checked it with valgrind and added the missing code for memory cleanup.

Comment: I checked the allocation time checking if allocated or not. Like what you have done. There has no error. Only when Im inserting value in the array by giving all 3 index error occures. Everything is done like your code. :(

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal: Please show the actual code. Maybe it's something as simple as an off-by-one error in your loops.

Comment: @undur_gongor: It depends on who you speak to. If you ask the majority of C contributors here, the cast is not desirable. I learned to program C on a system where the casts were mandatory, in the days before the C89 standard, when `malloc()` returned a `char *`, and on a machine where the bit pattern for the `char *` value of an address was different from the `int *` value of the same address (so not casting led to crashes). I don't castigate people for doing what was once necessary. It is explicit. If you compile with prototypes always required, the problems people worry about don't happen.

Comment: @harpun: thanks for adding the release code and testing with `valgrind`.  I've left your code in place, tagged with your name, but formatted as I'd format it if I wrote it inline like that.  In practice, as with the Version 2 code, I'd use a function to release the array.  I also completed the 'cleanup on allocation failure' code.  If you're able/willing to test that under `valgrind`, I'd be delighted to know the result (and I'll fix the bugs if there are any).

Comment: If you comment out `for (fail_after = 0; fail_after < 33; fail_after++)` in `main()`, then the code is valid. Otherwise you get out of memory errors and of course memory leaks.

Comment: @harpun: thanks for checking.  Now my Linux box is available, I was able to run `valgrind` on the code and track the problem.  It now runs clean.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes. Its working. but in the actual program same not working. May be like this indexing problem occurring. I will check and reply. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but, to be blunt: this is a horrid way of handling a 3D array: a double-nested loop with a bucketload of calls to `malloc()`, then triple-indirection to get a value at runtime. Yeuch! :o)

The conventional way of doing this (in the HPC community) is to use a one-dimensional array and do the index computation yourself. Suppose index `i` iterates over `nx` *planes* in the *x* direction, `j` iterates over `ny` *pencils* in the *y* direction, and `k` iterates over `nz` cells in the *z* direction. Then a pencil has `nz` elements, a plane has `nz*ny` elements, and the whole “brick” has `nz*ny*nx` elements. Thus, you can iterate over the whole structure with:

```
for(i=0; i<nx; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<ny; j++) {
        for(k=0; k<nz; k++) {
            printf("a(%d,%d,%d) = %d\n", i, j, k, a[(i*ny+j)*nz+k]);
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this construction is that you can allocate it with a single call to `malloc()`, rather than a boatload of nested calls:

```
int *a;
a = malloc(nx*ny*nz*sizeof(int));
```

The construction `x=a[i][j][k]` has three levels of indirection: you have to fetch an address from memory, `a`, add an offset, `i`, fetch that address from memory, `a[i]`, add an offset, `j`, fetch that address from memory, `a[i][j]`, add an offset, `k`, and (finally) fetch the data, `a[i][j][k]`. All those intermediate pointers are wasting cache-lines and TLB entries.

The construction `x=a[(i*ny+j)*nz+k]` has *one* level of indirection at the expense of two additional integer multiplications: compute the offset, fetch address, 'a', from memory, compute and add the offset, (i*ny+j)*nz+k, fetch the data.

Furthermore, there is essentially no way *whatsoever* of improving the triple-indirection method's performance based on data-access patterns. If we were *actually* visiting every cell, we could do something like this to avoid some of the overhead of index computation.

```
ij = 0;
for(i=0; i<nx; i++) {
    ii=i*ny;
    for(j=0; j<ny; j++) {
        ij=(ii+j)*nz;
        for(k=0; k<nz; k++) {
            printf("a(%d,%d,%d) = %d\n", i, j, k, a[ij+k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on what you're doing, this may not be great either, and there all alternative layouts and indexing methods (such as Morton or Ahnenteufel indexing) that may be more suitable, depending on your access patterns. I'm not trying to give a complete treatise on 3D Cartesian grid representation or indexing, merely illustrate that a “three star” solution is very bad for numerous reasons.

Comment: +1: I agree with your conclusion that a 3D array is better handled as you show and not as shown in the question.  On the other hand, if coded with (rather a lot of) care, the 3D notation can be made to work.  It is irksome for all concerned that the OP won't show the real code that is crashing as it is very difficult to diagnose problems in invisible code.

Comment: I agree that the 3D notation can be made to work (as a layer on top of the conventional 1D solution), but at the expense of more memory ((nx+ny)*sizeof(int(*)) and lots of extra dereferencing at runtime. OK for very small grids, maybe, but I see no reason not to do it the conventional way to begin with. If you are really burning to have the convenience of “i,j,k” style indexing, you can do it with a macro.

Answer (score 0):

By using `(*a)[l][h][0]` you are trying to de-reference a plain int and not a pointer.

use `a[l][h][0]` directly to assign any value to it.

Comment: The actual variable is in main() that is ***a. It is passed as parameter &a in the function. So using * in front of a

Comment: How did you declare the function 1[ <ret type > funcname ( int**** a) {...}

Comment: And agree with the fact from some one above that we need a complete example, the allocation code could have an issue [ like the no1 being 0 etc ]