# Undoing changes in C dynamic data structures when memory shortage occurs in the middle of operation

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures, out-of-memory

I'm implementing some complicated data structure in C supporting various operations. This data structure uses many other dynamic structures (graphs, AVL trees, linked lists) and everything is using dynamic memory.

When doing some operation, for example insertion to my data structure, obviously I have to allocate memory, sometimes lots of it (so the structure grows). This can lead to memory shortage (malloc() returning NULL) in the middle of performing some operation. Now, I would like not to terminate my program, but let the caller of the operation know that operation failed and let the caller continue executing.

My problem is that when operation fails in the middle of its execution due to memory allocation failure, I would like to undo what was done since calling of the operation, undo those changes in the data structure, so as if this operation was never called (so revert the data structure to the state right before executing the operation). I need this because I want my data structure to be in a valid and usable state even if an operation fails, so I can continue using it.

Since the data structure is quite advanced, I'm looking for general methods, hints and tips regarding reverting dynamic data structure to its' state right before calling an operation. Maybe you have some experience in handling such issues, heard of this problem or can suggest some books/articles regarding it or related source codes.

EDIT: A little simplified example would be set<> from C++. According to STL documentation, set::insert works well even when exception is thrown, so it is somehow able to revert changes made during execution of set::insert even though underlying data structure of set (red-black trees probably) is quite advanced.

Quote from cplusplus.com: "If a single element is to be inserted, there are no changes in the container in case of exception (strong guarantee).
Otherwise, the container is guaranteed to end in a valid state (basic guarantee)."

Comment: It sounds like your want the operations to be in a "transaction". Searching for that or Software Transactional Memory may turn up answers.

Comment: Have you actually observed `malloc` returning `NULL`. One of the dirty little secrets of modern operating systems is that `malloc` may return a non-NULL pointer even when no memory is available. See for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750796).

Comment: I'm more interested in conceptual techniques of handling this issue. I am implementing this in C, but would like to be able to adopt similar techniques in case of other languages.

Comment: The cleanup code typically ends up being much longer and more convoluted than the allocation code it is cleaning up. Absent automatic support via software transactional memory, you have to keep appropriate records of the 'before' state and make the changes carefully so that you can recover it.  You also need to decide what to do if a `realloc()` changes the location of a grown block of memory. Is it OK to resize the new block down to the original size, or must you be able to return the original pointer. If you must return the original pointer, the chances are that you can't use `realloc()`.

Comment: As an example, see the 3D memory allocation code discussed in [Segmentation fault error in 3D array memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579583/segmentation-fault-error-in-3d-array-memory-allocation).   Since you mention C++, you might want to think about using it.  Its constructors and destructors and modern C++ idioms for moving memory/objects makes the process easier to manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach for handling such cases, is you first do a dry run and allocate the memory required for the entire operation. And actually make the update only if all the allocations succeed.

Of course this might not *always* be possible because you might have to call other operations that do not have the "dry run" mode or some allocations might not be revealed until you actually perform the operation. For such cases, duplicating the data structure is usually the best option. Again, since the duplication is a read only operation, it is easy to abort and reverse.

The user might want to avoid the overhead of duplication and tracking extra data structures or doing dry runs. So this feature can be made as an optional feature (maybe use `#ifdef`), where the user can choose between reversing the operation or terminating the entire program.

Comment: I agree with the dry run approach. But duplication seems like it makes the problem worse, since you'll need to allocate memory to create the duplicate.

Comment: @user3386109 yes, but if that allocation fails you can abort easily since you haven't modified anything yet. I agree it is not the best solution but some times it is the only suitable solution especially if rollback wasn't included in the design from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ one common approach is to construct the result in a form of "temporary" and then  swap the temporary and the result. You might also do additional changes that cannot fail after the swap.

You might look at [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for inspiration - even if that is a specific use of the swap, and you might not need the copy-part.